# Java Synchronize Method Execution One After Another Depending on Method Response

Tags: java, spring, synchronize

I would like to ask how I could implement sequential execution on methods depending on method's response.

Example:

```
public void processTicketing() throws TicketingException {  

   /** Process Steps 1-4 could throw TicketingException and does not have exact time of how long each methods will be processed. 
    *  ? By default, is the sequence of process executions below followed from steps 1 to 4, Depending on how long each methods runs?
    *  If it is, then disregard this question on processes 1 to 4.
   */ 

   processStep1();
   processStep2();  
   processStep3();  
   processStep4();  

   for(int x=0; x < 10; x++){  
       //each call to this method should wait till the process is finish before calling the next one.
       executeTicketCommand(); 
   }  
}  


private void executeTicketCommand() throws TicketingException {
    //NOTE:
    //Send Request to a Web Service
    //Web Service sends back a response with a status of the process
    //The slower the internet, the slower the processing would be
    //I want this method to finish first the processing, before being called again inside the calling loop.

    if(hasError) throw new TicketingException("Error Processing Ticketing Command");
}
```

I am not sure whether to use synchronize or asynchronize for this scenario.

I am more concerned with the method execution of executeTicketCommand() since currently, they are invoked even if the previous executeTicketCommand() is not yet finished.

I am getting responses from the later executeTicketCommand() executions that I should wait for the current ticketing process to finish before I would start processing the next commands. This is something like lock the operation while it is still processing, after the processing... it can be run or called again.

This sample is just a representation to simplify the problem code as the real code is really complicated.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you expect that you don't have in your code snippet?

Comment: I am not so sure where I needed to add the keyword synchronized. For example, the executeTicketCommand() could run simultaneously without waiting for the first call to finish. The executeTicketCommand() should be finished first before calling the next.

Comment: Lets say the executeTicketCommand() would return a response OK, Warning or Throw an exception. If there are no errors during the executeTicketCommand() call, it will proceed to the next iteration and run it again.

Comment: If you need to execute everything sequentially, you have no need to synchronize access to anything as it should be done by one single thread unless you need to prevent several threads to execute your method processTicketing at the same time.

Comment: Currently, with the given code. It continue to call executeTicketCommand() ten times, even if each call is not yet finished processing. With that I am worried that processStep1() to 4 could proceed running steps 1 to 4 even if each process is not yet done.

Comment: You mean that executeTicketCommand is executed asynchronously?